# C# Custom OCR that returns a formatted string

Tags: c#, ocr

Just for my personal interest, I see from my research that it's not that easy to start your own OCR. However, I would like to hear ideas on how to achieve the challenge of not just recognising characters, but also giving back the results in the formatted string.
For example, I have an image of a table (imagine that it's an image with "|" and "_" being drawn straight lines):

---

|Number, AnotherNumber|Some Text|

---

|1,4                  |Blah     |

---

And after using a silent OCR, I get the result as "|Number, AnotherNumber|SomeText|\n|1,4|Blah|"
Any ideas of how could I achieve this, and what available tools/libraries I could make use of? I also would like to write this in C# with Visual Studio 2010. And ideally to work with PDFs but different image formats are fine. I've already looked at some, but they seem non-compatible as they use C++ or C.
Thank you.
Alina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting ocr libaries is quite hard (of course just if you dont pant to pay for it)
you could try this one, its not free but if you have office 2007: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41709/How-To-Use-Office-2007-OCR-Using-C

Comment: The only trick that I'm faced with, is that I'd need the OCR that would recognise a drawn line as "|" "_" type of characters on a table. Is there something pre-cooked for that out there? Or could I get an open library and extend it with such functionality, if I could? Thanks.

Comment: I would also be happy to start my own OCR from scratch if I could. In that case, what would be useful to me?